# Removing element from jQuery array gives undefined error

Tags: jquery, arrays, splice

I have an Array in jQuery. I would like to remove all elements that have a certain value in a selected field. When I do a loop and splice, I get an error.

```
$.each(arr,function(idx,val) {
    if (arr[idx].field == "something") {
        arr.splice(idx,1);
    }
});
```

I understand why I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined
```

...but I'm having trouble figuring out the best approach. A little bit of research shows signs that grep might be the right approach. Any suggestions?

*** ANSWER ***

In the end, this is what I did. Anyone have a better answer?:

```
for (var idx=0; idx<arr.length; idx++)
{
    if (arr[idx].field == "something") {
        arr.splice(idx,1);
        idx--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  for loop. Length of arr is changing dynamically

```
var length= arr.length;
for(var i=0; i<length ; i++){
    if (arr[i].field == "something") {
        arr.splice(i,1);
        length = arr.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$.each(arr,function(idx,val) {
    if (arr[idx] == "something") {
        arr.splice(idx,1);
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZhL64/)**

In your example `field` has no meaning. `arr[idx]` gets the value.

Comment: The thing is that "field" is just nameholder for an actual field in my array... so it's required.

Comment: Then how about posting your actual array?

Comment: This is what I'm doing. What do you think: for (var idx=0; idx<widgetFiles.length; idx++)
  {
   if (widgetFiles[idx].widget_id == widget_id) {
    widgetFiles.splice(idx,1);
    idx--;
   }
  }